# How do I classify documents with SciKitLearn using TfIdfVectorizer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The following example shows how one can train a classifier with the Sklearn 20 newsgroups data.

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer 
>>> categories = ['alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc', 'comp.graphics', 'sci.space']
>>> newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', ... categories=categories) 
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer() >>> vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(newsgroups_train.data) 
>>> vectors.shape (2034, 34118)
```

However, I have my own labeled corpus that I would like to use.

After getting a tfidfvector of my own data, would I train a classifier like this?

```
classif_nb = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(vectorizer)
```

To recap:
How can I use my own corpus instead of the 20newsgroups, but in the same way used here?
How can I then use my TFIDFVectorized corpus to train a classifier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address questions from comments; The whole basic process of working with tfidf representation in some classification task you should:

1. You **fit** the vectorizer to your training data and save it in some variable, lets call it **tfidf**
2. You **transform** training data (without labels, just text) through data = tfidf.transform(...)
3. You **fit** the model (classifier) using some_classifier.fit( data, labels ), where labels are in the same order as documnents in data
4. During testing you use tfidf.transform( ... ) on new data, and check the **prediction** of your model

Answer (score 2):

In general, for sklearn the flow is:

1. Convert your string data to numeric values usinf some vectorizer for e.g. TfIDF,count etcs
2. fit and transform
3. Pass it to train/fit of your choice of classifier.

You did not mention your data format but if it is csv file with some rows,flow could be:

1. Read each row of text
2. Pre process, like remove the stop words etc.
3. raw_data_list = [row1,row2,rown...]
4. vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
5. x_transformed = vectorizer.fit_transform(raw_data_list)
6. x_transformed can be passed to fit/train function of classifiers.

And once you have trained classifier you can call predict for new data.
Remeber to convert new data to same format as data on which you trained by using above used and fitted vectorizer before passing it to classif.predict.

Comment: I have a database with 1500 documents, each document is prelabeled. So basically I can turn it into an array of tuples, dictionaries, whatever.

Comment: I still don't understand how I would pass the labels of the documents to the classifier using tfidfvectorizer?

Comment: labels are **not** the part of representation, classifiers implement "fit(X,Y)" method, where X-data representation, Y-labels

Comment: @lejlot So basically I have my transformed data, and an array of labels that are in the same order that my raw_data_list was in? So that each document corresponds with a label?

Comment: Also, for tfidf vectorizer, when I convert my new data I want to classify, how would I vectorize only that one new document given my already vectorized corpus? Do i have to save the vectorized corpus?

Comment: @Yoni , yes, ordering of the data and labels is the only correspondence you give to the model.Regarding vectorizer - you should **save** it once you **fit** the data from the training corpus (to some variable) and then use this object to **tranform** any new data

Comment: @Yoni as lejlot mentioned, you should save your vectorizer and classifier both after you are done with training. You can simply pickle it so that you can load and use it for your prediction purposes.

Comment: ... or wrap them in a `Pipeline`.

Comment: @lejlot I follow your instructions but i'm getting another error, I may be using .transform incorrectly, I tried calling it with vectorizer.transform() and x_transformed.transform(), it didn't work.

Comment: you should ask another question when you have **different** problem, not edit the oridinal one and report other issues

Comment: @lejlot .. how about if I have multiple labels for a document and how do I convert the labels into numbers for processing ? getting confused over it..

Comment: it depends whether these labels are mutually exclusive (can one document have many labels? or are these "categories"?) - either way you should ask the **separate** question about it