# SVM value error text classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

I've gone through Scikit-SVM tutorial, and written the code to train and test. But I'm facing an issue with prediction, where it says, 'shape should be equal to training shape'. Here is the code below.

EDIT1: Sample Data

```
ERROR_DESC  CLASSIFICATION_LABEL
ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)  --  ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1095),INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS-Database-RAISE_SERVICENOW_DB_CREDENTIALS
A client error (ThrottlingException) occurred when calling the DescribeCluster operation: Rate exceeded   fetching DNS name  --  ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)  --  ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1095), NETWORK_ERROR-Database-RAISE_SERVICENOW_DB_CONNECTION
```

I also found a similar question on SO: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173010/error-in-testing-svm-classifier-for-text-classification) I tried to use transform, but it throws a different error.

```
import pandas as pd
​
# data paths
data_in = '../data/input/file.csv'
​
df_data = pd.read_csv(data_in)

# lower case all columns for uniformity
df_data.columns = map(str.lower, df_data.columns)
# lower case all data for uniformity
df_data = df_data.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())

labels = df_data['classification_label'].unique()

label_map = {}
i = 1
for label in labels:
    label_map[label] = i
    i += 1
​    

# apply map to classification_label column 
# df_data['classification_label'] = df_data['classification_label'].map(lambda s: label_map.get(s) if s in label_map else s)

# select features and labels
df_final = df_data[['error_desc', 'classification_label']]


from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
v = TfidfVectorizer()
X = v.fit_transform(df_final['error_desc'])
y = df_final['classification_label']


from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
​
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
  X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42
)


from sklearn.svm import SVC
​
def train_svm(X, y):
    """
    Create and train the Support Vector Machine.
    """
    svm = SVC(C=1000000.0, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf')
    svm.fit(X, y)
    return svm



svm = train_svm(X_train, y_train)



from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
​
# Make an array of predictions on the test set
pred = svm.predict(X_test)
​
# Output the hit-rate and the confusion matrix for each model
print(svm.score(X_test, y_test))
print(confusion_matrix(pred, y_test))



0.777777777778
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]



pred_x = """ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)  --  ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1095)"""
​


pred_x_vector = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform([pred_x])


svm.predict(pred_x_vector)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-130bf7f79131> in <module>()
----> 1 svm.predict(pred_x_vector)

/Users/userOne/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in predict(self, X)
    571             Class labels for samples in X.
    572         """
--> 573         y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
    574         return self.classes_.take(np.asarray(y, dtype=np.intp))
    575 

/Users/userOne/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in predict(self, X)
    308         y_pred : array, shape (n_samples,)
    309         """
--> 310         X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
    311         predict = self._sparse_predict if self._sparse else self._dense_predict
    312         return predict(X)

/Users/userOne/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.pyc in _validate_for_predict(self, X)
    477             raise ValueError("X.shape[1] = %d should be equal to %d, "
    478                              "the number of features at training time" %
--> 479                              (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
    480         return X
    481 

ValueError: X.shape[1] = 49 should be equal to 554, the number of features at training time
```

Comment: You can only use a trained model to predict vectors of the same size, in this case the TfidfVectorizer creates a vector according to the size of the new vocab, you could use vocabulary parameter but you will have to save the original vocabulary first, let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: @EzerK Im a beginner, so please pardon me. Is there a code that you can share or point me to a better approach

Comment: if you'l post a sample data , I can try and fix your code

Comment: @EzerK Added the data, label is after comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df_data = pd.DataFrame([['ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)  --  ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1095)','INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS-Database-RAISE_SERVICENOW_DB_CREDENTIALS'],\
['A client error (ThrottlingException) occurred when calling the DescribeCluster operation: Rate exceeded   fetching DNS name  --  ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)  --  ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1095)', 'NETWORK_ERROR-Database-RAISE_SERVICENOW_DB_CONNECTION']])

df_data.columns = ['ERROR_DESC' , 'CLASSIFICATION_LABEL']

# lower case all columns for uniformity
df_data.columns = map(str.lower, df_data.columns)

# select features and labels
df_final = df_data[['error_desc', 'classification_label']]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
v = TfidfVectorizer()
X = v.fit_transform(df_final['error_desc'])
y = df_final['classification_label']
orig_vocab = v.get_feature_names() #save the orig vocabulary

from sklearn.svm import SVC

def train_svm(X, y):
    """
    Create and train the Support Vector Machine.
    """
    svm = SVC(C=1000000.0, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf')
    svm.fit(X, y.values)
    return svm

svm = train_svm(X, y)

pred_x = """ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448) at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)  --  ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1095)"""
pred_x_vector =   TfidfVectorizer(vocabulary=orig_vocab).fit_transform([pred_x]) #vectorize by original vocabulary

svm.predict(pred_x_vector)
```

Explanation:

A trained model can only predict on vectors the same size as the vectors it trained upon. Therefore in cases of vectorizing text by bag of words methods you must keep the original vocabulary of the train sample in order to create vectors according to the same vocabulary.

Remarks:

1. Used only two samples, so no train test split (just trained on both) and therefore no cross validation
2. no need to lower case the data sklearn vectorizer does that for you.

Comment: Okay, but the prediction is incorrect, it labels it incorrect - any idea?

Comment: got  'INCORRECT_CREDENTIALS-Database-RAISE_SERVICENOW_DB_CREDENTIALS' - is that wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the other, but I do have 83 rows - is that the case? Is there a way to print the prediction score? But I'll accept your answer as you have helped me. But if you can provide some guidance that will also help :)

Comment: Thanks. looking on one example is usually not helpful, you should print out all your False predictions and try to understand what went wrong. in any case 83 is usually not sufficient for  machine learning